# Error: can't create trigger properly (ORA-24344: success with compilation error ORA-06512). Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

Oracle APEX. I want to create trigger: if user deletes a row where ENDDATE is null the row won't be deleted overwise it will. This is my script:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE  TRIGGER CHECK_NOT_NULL_
    BEFORE DELETE ON CAREER
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF(OLD.ENDDATE IS NULL) 
        INSERT INTO CAREER VALUES (OLD.JOBNO, OLD.EMPNO, OLD.STARTDATE, OLD.ENDDATE);
    END IF;
END CHECK_NOT_NULL_;
```

But I have ORA-24344 error. Can you explain why and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: what error is printed when `SQL> show errors` issued ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger attempts to re-insert the row if the END_DATE is null. This won't work (you'll get [the notorious mutating table error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oracle%20mutating%20table)). But anyway, if you want to prevent deletion of the row it's simpler and clearer to simply do that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  TRIGGER CHECK_NOT_NULL_
    BEFORE DELETE ON CAREER
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :OLD.ENDDATE IS NULL THEN 
       raise_application_error(-20000, 'Cannot delete a row when ENDDATE is null');
    END IF;
END CHECK_NOT_NULL_;
```

This fails the action and tells the user **why** their action was refused. Silently undoing a user's action is bad practice, because it's mystifying, and mystified users are unhappy and often angry users.

Answer (score 0):

Precede all `old`s with a colon `:`, i.e.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  TRIGGER CHECK_NOT_NULL_
    BEFORE DELETE ON CAREER
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF(:OLD.ENDDATE IS NULL) 
        INSERT INTO CAREER VALUES (:OLD.JOBNO, :OLD.EMPNO, :OLD.STARTDATE, :OLD.ENDDATE);
    END IF;
END CHECK_NOT_NULL_;
```

Also, I'd suggest you to name all columns you're inserting into, e.g.

```
insert into career (jobno, empno, startdate, enddate)
  values (:old.jobno, :old.empno, :old.startdate, :old.enddate);
```

Comment: I don't know either, as you didn't provide any useful info. What happens? Any error? If so, which one?